# Should I use my personal GitHub account for work?

Tags: github

I have both a personal and a work GitHub account.

Switching between them is a pain; even though the CLI identity management is doable ([1](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-how-to-work-with-github-and-%20multiple-accounts--net-22574), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9347458/switch-between-user-identities-in-one-git-on-one-computer)), logging in and out from GitHub's excellent website is extremely annoying.

Is there anything wrong with using a personal GitHub account at work?

Is there formal GitHub advice on this topic?

Comment: GitHub suggest you don't have two accounts, so you can start from there

Comment: I don't think this question is primarily opinion-based. Github explicitly recommends using your personal account, while the alternative is annoying and error prone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It's recommended that you use your personal github account for work.

On their help page [Merging multiple user accounts](https://help.github.com/articles/merging-multiple-user-accounts/):

> If you have separate accounts for work and personal use, you can merge the accounts.
>
> **Tip:** We recommend using only one user account to manage both personal and professional repositories.

On their help page [Can I create accounts for people in my organization?](https://help.github.com/articles/can-i-create-accounts-for-people-in-my-organization/):

> While you can add users to an organization you've created, you can't create personal user accounts on behalf of another person.
>
> Because you access an organization by logging in to a personal account, each of your team members needs a personal account. Once you have user names for each person you'd like to add to your organization, you can add them to teams.

It works.